# How do we choose between two scientific ideas when both aren't yet falsified?

Tags: epistemology

Consider a leading theory for a phenomenon, then how are new theories shown to be better while both remain unfalsified?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about philosophy of science in general, not physics as a natural science specifically. (Three other close voters chose "primarily opinion-based" as a reason, while one chose "needs details or clarity")

Comment: Additionally, this question seems to make a lot of unspoken assumptions - the use of "unfalsified" seems to presuppose an approach to epistemology in the style of Popper, as does the idea that theories are shown to be "better" than others (Kuhn and Feyerabend would like to have a word with you about [incommensurability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(philosophy_of_science)))

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this question (and many of the answers). The place to begin understanding what I think this question is asking is David Deutsch's paper on [the logic of experimental tests](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02048.pdf).

Answer (score 54):

The very bare minimum that a theory has to obey to be considered as viable is:

- The theory is self-consistent (it cannot predict two different results for the same input)
- The theory is complete (within its domain of applicability, any statement can be decided by the theory)
- The theory agrees with all past experiments

The falsifiability part is basically related to the third criteria: if a newer experiment cannot be explained by the theory, it is falsified.

What to do if two theories on the same domain of applicability obey all three? Here are a few options!

**Don't do anything!**

For a while now, physics has overall tried to be about applying models more than trying to find [some kind of metaphysical truth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRyoe2cgCYs). With this in mind, there is nothing fundamentally wrong about having two theories for the same domain, especially if they have about the same predictions for any reasonable experiment.

Things may not be ideal, of course. Competing theories may have wildly different predictions (although that is less of a problem in physics usually). Also there are finite resources for research, and it may be useful to determine which theory is more promising, more practical, or *closer to the fundamental truth*. There are many, many criteria I could bring up, stemming from [made-up examples](https://slatestarcodex.com/2019/11/18/more-intuition-building-on-non-empirical-science-three-stories/) (it's a big hobby of philosophers of science), but I'll try to stick to realistic cases.

**Apply heuristics**

There are many broad bias in physics which have shown to be more likely to lead to better models than others. There are no fundamental reasons why these should lead to better theories, but so far they seem to be productive, if not metaphysically true :

- Try to go for the simpler theory. "Simpler" is of course somewhat vague, and different people may have different opinions on what constitutes a simpler theory. A few cases can be useful, though. Overall, people will pick general relativity over the Einstein-Cartan theory (general relativity + a torsion field), Brans-Dicke theory (general relativity + a scalar field), or other versions that are general relativity with additional terms, since any of those additional objects have such low impact on actual experiments. We went with quantum chromodynamics rather than the patchwork of formulas we had with the meson zoo of particles.
- Try to go for a local theory. It's generally assumed that causal effects are always local, and only propagate from their point of origin.
- Symmetries tend to play a big role in modern theories, and relatedly, conserved quantities that stem from them. We tend to favor theories if they stem from some underlying principle of symmetry, and we prefer if the big conservation laws hold, at least locally (conservation of energy, momentum, charge, etc). Fred Hoyle's gravitational theory was in part not liked too much for breaking local time translation symmetry, and therefore conservation of energy. The neutrino was inferred from conservation of energy, and the theories that went against it didn't pan out.
- The second law of thermodynamics looms large in a lot of physicists' minds, and overall, any theory that would imply a break of it is considered suspicious.
- Causality is generally considered very important. This is why naked singularities, closed timelike curves or time-symmetric theories are not considered to be likely to be physical. This is linked to another concept, determinism. While not all modern theories are deterministic, they are at least probabilistic. Theories that allow for events to happen with no assigned probability are generally considered pathological.

Beware that many such heuristics existed in the past and have been shown to be wrong, or at least not necessarily best. Galilean invariance, celestial objects moving on circles, etc.

**Go for the practical theory**

A big part of the appeal of a theory is its ability to get results, and get them easily enough. If a theory seems promising, but the mathematics necessary to even obtain measurable outcomes isn't there, or fairly intractable, it may be best to go with the simpler theory. It's best to keep measurable quantities obtainable, in realistic scenarios, with reasonable computation times.

Another practical aspect: ideally, a theory should be such that we can apply it without omniscience. If a theory requires the knowledge of too many initial conditions, it is not going to be terribly applicable in experiments. Ideally the influence of most of the universe should be either very small, or can be approximated by some general principles. This is common in most theories: inverse square laws, the cluster decomposition principle, mean fields, etc.

**Raw philosophical bias**

A lot of choices in theory on the individual level is simply due to their own ideas on ontology, causality, epistemology, and other metaphysical business. This is what drives a lot of adherents of fringe theories, the fights between competing theories for new physics, as well as some of the choices regarding what is established science. It's entirely possible to have theories without any ontology, where we simply input a list of measurements in formulas and get another list of measurements, but in addition to being impractical, most people believe in some kind of physical objects, and the theories tend to reflect those ontologies. A lot of people don't like the Copenhagen interpretation due to its lack of determinism, or its contextuality. Many of the heuristics I listed are rooted in philosophical positions, in addition to being seen as generally useful. There was some resistance to general relativity from the idea of Kant that Euclidian geometry was fundamental. A lot of science in the Soviet Union was constrained by the requirement that it had to obey dialectic materialism, which favored deterministic quantum theories and eternal cosmologies. Opinions on what constitutes a reasonable spacetime in general relativity can be rooted a lot in the author's opinion on causality or the nature of time (presentism, growing block, eternalism, whether time is cyclical, eternal or has a starting point, etc).

Comment: Excellent answer, +1. In the section on simplicity you say “different people may have different opinions on what constitutes a simpler theory”. There currently is increasing interest in and acceptance of Bayesian inference and methods. In the Bayesian framework simplicity becomes objective and both Occham’s razor and Popper’s falsifiability are turned into quantitative mathematical principles.

Comment: The most important aspect of science is that you can prove things wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't you want, all else equal, to favor the older theory?  Imagine - theory A is put forward, it correctly predicts the results of a novel experiment X.  Later, theory B is developed and also "explains" X, but that result was already known.  So, while I think this is an excellent answer you may wish to consider a higher hurdle for the new theory - which I think is something that was on the OP's mind.

Comment: You can also go with the tried-and-true option of picking the theory that best aligns with your politics.

Comment: Usually less of a problem in physics

Comment: No theory is complete.. No theory can decide each of its statements.. This is basic logic. For example, even in a maximally idealised case the statement Solar system will stay bounded forever(for all t) is undecidable within classical mechanics.

Comment: Plenty of physical theories are decidable as far as measurements go, ie you can show that system of classical mechanics (with a computable force) can be worked out with arbitrary precision.

Comment: (The statement that the solar system will stay bounded forever is not measurable since we cannot perform measurements infinitely far in the future!)

Comment: @PaulYoung Why would the other theory get more favour than the new one, all else equal?  An older theory which does all the same things is no more likely to be correct than the newer one, as far as the scientific method is concerned.  How would you determine if the first theory was closer to the fundamental truth, or the second one?

Comment: Good answer! Some misunderstand and then believe things like Einstein proved Newton wrong or argue that wave/particle models can't both be right. "Simpler" theories (often) break down at some point (like Newton's gravitation) but they are still good enough for "everyday" use.

Comment: An example: In the early days of thermodynamics, there was a solid debate as to whether heat and cold were two different substances.  It took quite a while to determine that differences in heat were identical in effect to negative differences in cold.  Until then, we simply had two theories going on.

Comment: @JMac - well, I think this may be the question ... should one theory trump another because it is older and has made an "out of sample" prediction (when all else is equal) .. or no?  A theory which has made a prediction - somehow - feels it has street cred?

Comment: @PaulYoung But is there any justification for that besides "feelings"?  I don't see the actual logic in placing one theory ahead of another just on the basis of being there first.  A simple counterpoint to that is that the first theory maybe just got lucky in the dark, whereas the new theory is based on findings that weren't even known at the time of the original theory.  You could argue by that logic, the newer theory should be used.  All things equal, I don't see an objective reason why you would choose one over the other.  From a scientific standpoint they should be equally justified.

Comment: @JMac - I dunno.  This is a question I wonder about myself.  But I can draw an analogy to neural net training - things like Alpha Zero, etc...  You often partition all your data into three parts ... you "train" the nets on part one, then you test them on part two ... you discard the nets that did poorly on part two and apply the survivors to part three.  Then you try training new nets on a combo of part one and part two (twice as much data) but, whaddaya know, they perform more poorly than the survivor nets trained on part one alone, but vetted by part two.   See what I mean?

Comment: @PaulYoung I can't quite follow how that analogy follows though.  For one, I don't know if scientific theories are analogous to neural nets in a way that applies.  Also, what is the analog of "testing" in this case?  The only way I really follow the analogy is if I consider the "testing" of the neural nets as comparing the theory to the measurements, in which case both of them would represent nets that passed the testing phase.

Comment: @JMac - I agree, I am not speaking with conviction here.  My point is very narrow - when something makes a correct prediction, I then place value on it.  I do not want to overstate my point.

Comment: @JMac: Good question! When there are many conceivable results of an experiment, a theory that was developed without knowledge of the actual result (e.g. because it predates it) can be tested by comparing its prediction to the actual result. It can fail that test, or it can pass it. But a theory that was only developed *with* knowledge of the actual result is, in effect, "cheating" on that test; it can't fail it, because we wouldn't know about it if it did. (But there are many exceptions to this argument; it's only a heuristic, like the others, and needs case-by-case analysis.)

Comment: @ruakh But it can fail it by the same mechanism as the other test, by not matching with observations in reality.  Again, it seems almost arbitrary.  Just because one theory was generated more "in the dark" about the results, it shouldn't actually make the theory more accurate.  If both theories meet all the conditions in the answer, what's to say that the later theory couldn't have been come up with before the result, had circumstances been a bit different?  It doesn't seem like a scientific way to put a value on theories to me.

Comment: @JMac: Re: "it can fail it by the same mechanism as the other test, by not matching with observations in reality": No, because of the file-drawer effect. Re: "it seems almost arbitrary": That's true of each of the heuristics in this answer. If theory X is simpler than theory Y, or X is local and Y isn't, or X is causal and Y isn't, etc., that shouldn't actually make X more accurate, provided that Y is fully compatible with all known laws of nature in domains where those laws have been shown to hold. So it's almost arbitrary to prefer X. And yet, scientists do.

Comment: Please remember that comments are not for extended discussions

Answer (score 10):

Some general philosophy-of-science answers...

- Occam's razor - prefer the "simpler" theory (of course a lot to discuss here)
- Generality - prefer the theory that explains more phenomena
- Specificity - prefer the theory that makes more detailed predictions (e.g. quantitative rather than just qualitative)
- Falsifiability - prefer the theory that is easier to falsify

A related, but personal, thought: there are downsides of viewing science as a search for the One Ultimate True Theory. There are infinitely many theories that cannot be distinguished by observations we can make in this universe. If one of them is "true", all of them are. So there is no One True Theory. So there's no mandate to always be picking between competing theories; this could be a fool's errand. Instead maybe science is about something else, say, a search for the most accurate (counterfactual) predictions: trying to be able to say what would happen if. In that case, theories would just be a means to this end and picking between them becomes more pragmatic and hinges a lot on falsifiability.

Comment: "There are infinitely many theories that cannot be distinguished by observations" - that all predict everything correctly?  Citation needed?

Comment: Occam's razor favors not simpler theory, theory can be very complex instead in terms of math etc. But rather it favors theories with **less assumptions**. For example string theory has assumptions that there exists "strings" and "extra dimensions". This introduces additional complexity compared over QM, because existence of most particles are proven already, etc. So in this respect string theory looses against QM.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That all predict everything we can possibly observe in this universe. Silly examples: we can take any theory and tweak its predictions on the scale of less than a Plank length (or whatever) or on collections of greater than $10^{10^{10}}$ particles, to get a different but indistinguishable theory.

Answer (score 1):

In this case they are not theories, but hypotheses. You use the one that seems more plausible or better explains the context that you work with.

In practice there are many *non-scientific* considerations that come into play: different schools/communities adhere to different hypotheses (particularly when the hypothesis originates form your supervisor or the supervisor of your supervisor). Sometimes they fight bitterly - both in journal pages and conferences, but also when it comes to getting positions, grants, etc. So one spends many years working in the framework of a particular hypothesis in a hope that it will be proven correct in the end.

Comment: +1 for admitting that quite often the rationale for supporting one hypothesis or another has little to do with science itself.

Comment: I've witnessed a few hot scientific debates in my life - these were not about the most fundamental issues, but interesting scientific puzzles anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Take quantum physics as a good example: regarding it as the "better" theory of everything does not mean that classical models need to (or will be) falsified. They will continue to be valid, and explain observations of our everyday lives with sufficient accuracy. What we want, is to see the building blocks of the old model emerge from what we get when we no longer seek to replace parts from old theories by new ones, but apply the new ones exclusively.